Problems with unlocking the phone after a standard software update
Recently, I updated my Infinix Hot 20i, and I encountered the following issue. The phone took a long time to update, and upon rebooting, it prompted me to enter the graphical key on the unlock screen.
I have a very simple pattern lock that I have not forgotten. However, when I enter the correct pattern, the phone thinks for about five seconds and then says that the pattern is incorrect. If I enter an incorrect pattern right away, it immediately shows an error.
Could you advise me on how to resolve this situation without losing my data, as I do not have a backup?
